# Query table A or table B based on some condition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, stored-functions

in an Oracle DB (12) I have 2 tables:

table: STEP_DETAILS

```
+-----------+---------+---------------+
| record_id | step_id | material_type |
+===========+=========+===============+
| 1         | 1       | in            |
+-----------+---------+---------------+
| 2         | 1       | in            |
+-----------+---------+---------------+
| 3         | 1       | out           |
+-----------+---------+---------------+
| 4         | 2       | in            |
+-----------+---------+---------------+
| 5         | 2       | out           |
+-----------+---------+---------------+
| 6         | 2       | out           |
+-----------+---------+---------------+
```

table: ACTIONS_DETAILS

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| record_id | action_id | material_type |
+===========+===========+===============+
| 1         | 11        | in            |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| 2         | 11        | out           |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| 3         | 12        | in            |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| 4         | 12        | out           |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

*all id-columns are of type INTEGER.*

I need to count the input materials for both tables.
in a PL/SQL block I have the following functions, each has 'almost' the same query:

```
--count from step_details:
FUNCTION get_step_input_count(p_step_id  step_details.step_id%TYPE)
  RETURN INTEGER
  IS
    l_count INTEGER := 0;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1)
      INTO l_count
      FROM step_details
     WHERE step_id = p_step_id
       AND material_type = 'in';

    RETURN l_count;
  END get_step_input_count;

--count from action_details:
  FUNCTION get_action_input_count(p_action_id  action_details.action_id%TYPE)
  RETURN INTEGER
  IS
    l_count INTEGER := 0;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1)
      INTO l_count
      FROM action_details
     WHERE action_id = p_action_id
       AND material_type = 'in';

    RETURN l_count;
  END get_action_input_count;
```

is it possible to write one single SELECT-statement that can query one of the 2 tables each time based on some condition, so I will eventually write one function that uses one query instead of 2 functions, something like:

```
  FUNCTION get_input_count(p_parent_id  integer,
                           p_from       varchar2)
  RETURN INTEGER
  IS
    l_count INTEGER := 0;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1)
      INTO l_count
      FROM (when p_from = 'S' then 'step_details'
            when p_from = 'A' then 'action_details')
     WHERE (when p_from = 'S' then 'step_id   = p_parent_id'
            when p_from = 'A' then 'action_id = p_parent_id')
       AND material_type = 'in';

    RETURN l_count;
  END get_input_count;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something like the following:

```
select sum(num_rows)
from
(
    select count(*) as num_rows
    from tab1                        /* first table */
    where :param = 1
    union all
    select count(*) as num_rows
    from tab2                        /* second table */
    where :param = 2 
)
```

Here you use a single `select` that wraps the `UNION ALL` of queries from all the possible tables; every table gives its contribution or not, depending on the value of some parameter, so that you only get the rows from the table you want, based on the parameter value.

Comment: what would happened if one of the unioned queries throws a NO_DATA_FOUND exception? say that we want to count from first table, so the first query works well, but for some reason the second query failed because of no_data_found. how would this affect the whole functionality?

Comment: No matter the tables, if one of the two queries fails you will have a zero count result, and not a no data found; if one table gives no result, you get the number of records of the other one. If both the queries give zero, you get zero as a result

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using dynamic SQL composed of concatenations for table and column names, and a bind variable for the value which will be common(`p_parent_id`) for querying from each tables.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_input_count(p_parent_id INT, p_from VARCHAR2) RETURN INT IS
    l_count INT;
    crs     SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_sql   VARCHAR2(32767);
    v_from  VARCHAR2(32);
    v_col   VARCHAR2(99);
BEGIN
    SELECT DECODE(p_from,'A','actions_details','S','step_details'),
           DECODE(p_from,'A','action_id','S','step_id')
      INTO v_from, v_col
      FROM dual;

     v_sql := 'SELECT COUNT(*) 
                 FROM '||v_from||' 
                WHERE material_type = ''in'' AND '||v_col||' = :prt_id';

     OPEN crs FOR v_sql USING p_parent_id; 
     LOOP       
        FETCH crs INTO l_count;
       EXIT WHEN crs%NOTFOUND;             
     END LOOP;

     CLOSE crs;

    RETURN l_count;
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1ae79fb4d91d2bc5527ef7ca2bd7c650)</kbd>

where

- initializing the value of `l_count` variable with zero is redundant,
  since the query will return zero without exception whenever no
  matching records found
- the keyword `FUNCTION` should be prepended by `CREATE [OR REPLACE]`
- ending the stored function with its name is optional(might be
  neglected)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use dynamic SQL like below.
SQL injection should be cared in this case.

```
sql_statement := 'select count(*)';
IF table = 'xxx'
THEN 
  sql_statement := sql_statement || ' from xxx where material_type = ''in''';
ELSIF table = 'yyy'
  sql_statement := sql_statement || ' from yyy where yyyy_type = ''in''';
END IF;
sql_statement := sql_statement blur blur;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_statement INTO l_count USING p_1;
```

Comment: table names cannot be used as bind variables within a dynamic SQL.